# Custom Settings and fields

Tags: customsetting

> I have created the custom setting with the hierarchy type

I have added some fields to the custom settings

**phone field is added to the custom settings**

**custom setting Name:Order_Configuration__c**

```
Phone :12345 - one profile

phone:456798 - another profile
```

Is it possible to access the different values for different profiles in custom settings using apex trigger code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the [CustomObject.getInstance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) method. You can provide the Organization Id, the Profile Id, or a User Id. Using this method, you can get the specific values for each User Id or Profile Id that has a specified hierarchy value.

Comment: @user36188 You can perform a query to determine which profile you want to find the Id for.

Comment: @user36188 `String SellingOfficePhone = Order_Configuration__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getProfileId())`.

Comment: @user36188 Yes, you have to query for the profiles first if you want to compare multiple profiles.

Comment: @user36188 `Profile[] profiles = [select id from profile where name in ('profile 1','profile 2')]; String[] values = new String[0]; for(Profile Id: profiles) values.add(Order_Configuration__c.getInstance(id));` ... approximately.

Comment: @user36188 Using the getInstance function that's already been mentioned.

Comment: @user36188 Sure, feel free to update your question if it'll help.

Comment: values.add(Order_Configuration__c.getInstance(id)); while saving it is showing error:Variable does not exist: Order_Configuration__c @sfdcfox

Comment: @user36188 You have to replace `Order_Configuration__c` with the name of your custom setting.

Comment: Please join me in [chat], assuming this works.

Answer (score 2):

```
CustomSetting__c CS = CustomSetting__c.getInstance(ProfileId);
```

More info here:-
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm